# Removing space from a list of strings taken from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

[image]

What I want to do that is take these as different strings in a list. For that I have written the following line

```
list_phonemes= df['HEADER'].astype(str).values.tolist()'
```

This does the job but the problem is that it retains the spaces and the output is like this

```
['M EH S S AH G EH',
 'P L AH S M EH S S EH NX JH AH R',
 'S K R IY EH N R IH K OO RX D IH NX G',
 'Y UH AH TH UH B EY V IY D IH Y OO S',
 'AE M EH ZH AA N P R AY M IY',
 'V AH R K OO AH T S S K AE N N AH R',
 'AA N V IY D IH Y OO',
 'N OO N IH',
 'P R AY M IY V IY D IH Y OO S',
 'P R OO F AY L EH']
```

But I want the strings without any spaces like

```
['MEHSSAHGEH',
 'PLAHSMEHSSEHNXJHAHR',
.
.
.
]
```

Is there any thing that I can add with this line `list_phonemes= df['HEADER'].astype(str).values.tolist()` so that I can achieve the output I am looking for rather than iterating over the entire list again just to remove the spaces?

Comment: For every string s in the list you can apply: `s.replace(" ", "")`

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
df.HEADER = df.HEADER.astype("str").apply(lambda x : x.replace(" ", ""))
```

Now convert it to list as you already did.

```
df.HEADER.values.tolist()
```

Comment: `df.HEADER = df.astype(str).HEADER.apply(x : x.replace(" ", ""))
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I am getting this error with this

Comment: updated it now! :) missed the `lamdba` keyword

Answer (score 0):

You could use `replace()` function.

```
list_phonemes= [string.replace(" ", "") for string in df['HEADER'].astype(str).values.tolist()']
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` this error I am getting

Comment: according to my knowledge `EOL` indicates that it can't find the *end of the string* therefore it reaches the *end of the line*. I don't know why its arising here. try replacing double quotes with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the spaces you can use:

list_phonemes = [item.replace(' ', '') for item in list_phonemes]